# SESSxxxxx cookie gets removed, $_SESSION data being lost but only locally

Tags: 7, sessions

I have just pulled deployed code down to my local setup, restarted MAMP, cleared the Drush cache, and started a process that relies on data stored in $_SESSION. We can confirm this works in prod - no data is lost from $_SESSION at any of the process' three steps.

However, when I submit data from step one and go to step two locally, the data disappears from $_SESSION. I've noticed that locally, the SESSxxxx cookie disappears when I submit my step one data.

Since this works in prod I believe my code is fine and there must be something wrong with my config, but everything related to the session cookie in `php.ini` is identical to my local setup.

Theres so many configs and moving pieces to checkout, is there a way I can see how the `session` table is being interacted with that might lead to clues as to what is going on? Or could the issue be in httpd.conf? or somewhere else?

Comment: If your Drupal site explicitly sets the cookie domain, and you are not using that domain when browsing to your MAMP site, then this might be the problem. Look in settings.php for a line that sets the [$cookie_domain](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/domain-access/configuring-settingsphp#s-cookie-domain). You can also create a virtual host on your MAMP server with the same domain as your production site, then edit your `/etc/hosts` to map that domain to the ip of your MAMP server (if it's on the same computer then 127.0.0.1).

Comment: You can use the network tab in Chrome DevTools to view the request and response cookies. Open the network tab, load/refresh a page on your MAMP site, click on the first item in the list, and look in the "Cookies" tab. If the SESSxxxxx cookie in the response has a different domain than the page you are on, then sessions will not work. Your browser will not (re)send a session cookie to a site with a different domain than what the cookie is configured for, even if it received the cookie from a request/response on that other domain.

Comment: Those are both great ideas, Ill be sure and post here if either work and tag you for credit